# yarn is not recognized as a command on git bash in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, git-bash

I installed yarn using npm: `npm i -g yarn`

when I execute the command `yarn -v` or any other yarn command on ***cmd*** or ***PowerShell*** it Outputs the Version

But on ***GitBash*** it displays: `C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`

I even tried Reinstalling Node & Yarn but it still doesn't work.

1 solution I found is that instead of yarn if I use `yarn.cmd` then it works in GitBash.

But I'm unable to find the reason & the correct solution for this problem. If someone has any Idea please Guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried so many things and in the end I'm not sure which really worked. Maybe you find out that another step works in your case.

**So here's some of the sensible things I did:**

1. I reinstalled node, yarn and git because that's the default behavior of a man in confusion. *(Didn't work)*
2. Tried manipulating PATH although yarn was recognized from cmd and powershell. *(Didn't work)*
3. I found this: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install. It seems like they updated the installation steps. So I tried that because it was something different from the yarn installation you and I used... **It worked!**

Now, if the last step was the one that worked, **make sure to run** `npm uninstall -g yarn` after

Comment: Thank You Very Much for the help, Following the new corepack approach Worked.